# How to configure maximum number of FTP connections on Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, configuration, ftp, connection

My server can handle up to 10 simultaneous FTP connections (or "workers"), but Netbeans only uses one by default.

This means I could sync my project up to 10 times faster, only if I knew **how to make Netbeans open simultaneous FTP connections**?